# Msacces linked table is slow after refresh in linked table manager

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an old System. 2005 SQL backend with access 2003 frontend. There are a lot of linked tables and querys from that tables, and other objects (not relevant). I made a modification on one table (column type from char(25) to varchar(50)). 
Then, I refresh the linked table information (in MSACCESS 2003 Menu->tools->database utilities->linked table manager), and the program become terrible slow.
Lot of tries later, I restored an older DB to SQL, and whitout any table modification, I refresh the linked table in MSACCESS, and the program become terrible slow again.

So I figured out, if I refresh the linked table (nothing modification in sql table), the access will be unuseable slow.
I have one significant query. It runs between 10-15 seconds. After the relinking it takes ~2 minutes.

Well, is there anyone who saw problem like this, or better, is there anyone who know solution for this problem.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the linked table in the frontend, then linking it again?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this solution, it doesn,t work!

Comment: Tried a compact & repair after relinking?

Comment: Thanks, now i tried. Unfortunately the result is the same.